# How to set spark in rstudio, spark_connect() can't work

Tags: apache-spark, sparklyr, rstudio-server

I installed R-3.4.0 and rstduio-server 1.1.447 in the centOS.  In the rstudio, i can't connect the spark like this :
[image]

```
 sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
  Error in validate_java_version(master, spark_home) : 
  Java is required to connect to Spark. Please download and install Java from https://www.java.com/en/
```

[image]
It said Java is required to connect to Spark. but i installed the JDK1.8 :

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111
```

[image]
i don't know how to connect spark. 
i think if i should set spark in the rstudio? The spark installed in the cluster by CDH, It's version is version 2.1.0.cloudera1. i add "SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2" in the Renviron file.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed JDK after installing R and starting RStudio, you may have to reconfigure R:

```
R CMD javareconf
```

and restart the server:

```
rstudio-server restart
```

both executed with `root` privileges.

Comment: the JDK installed before the R and RStudio,  i will try it your way .

Comment: I follow your method, but the problem also have.  can you give me any other advice ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

now it connect! 
I use command "Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="  ")" .